# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (e^{\sin{\frac{1}{n}}} -1)\ x^n, x > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (e^{\sin{\frac{1}{n}}} -1)\  x^n, x > 0$

I tried using the limit comparison test for $x \ge 1$ with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin{\frac{1}{n}}$ which is divergent, so my series will be divergent also.

But i do not know how to solve for $x < 1$.

Any tips ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(e^{\sin(1/n)}-1\right)x^n}{x^n/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(e^{\sin(1/n)}-1\right)=1$$since, if $f(x)=e^{\sin x}$, then $f'(0)=1$. So, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$ converges in $(0,1)$ and diverges in $[1,\infty)$, so does your series.